# ColumnTransformer(s) in various parts of a pipeline do not play well

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, mlxtend

I am using `sklearn` and `mlxtend.regressor.StackingRegressor` to build a stacked regression model.
For example, say I want the following small pipeline:

1. A Stacking Regressor with two regressors:

   - A pipeline which:

     - Performs data imputation
     - 1-hot encodes categorical features
     - Performs linear regression
   - A pipeline which:

     - Performs data imputation
     - Performs regression using a Decision Tree

Unfortunately this is not possible, because `StackingRegressor` doesn't accept `NaN` in its input data.
This is even if its regressors know how to handle `NaN`, as it would be in my case where the regressors are actually pipelines which perform data imputation.

However, this is not a problem: I can just move data imputation outside the stacked regressor.
Now my pipeline looks like this:

1. Perform data imputation
2. Apply a Stacking Regressor with two regressors:

   - A pipeline which:

     - 1-hot encodes categorical features
     - Standardises numerical features
     - Performs linear regression
   - An `sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor`.

One might try to implement it as follows (the entire minimal working example in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/alberto-santini/d2c7572b499dea124a0160406fcf2e40), with comments):

```py
sr_linear = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('preprocessing', ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
        ('categorical',
             make_pipeline(OneHotEncoder(), StandardScaler()),
             make_column_selector(dtype_include='category')),
        ('numerical',
             StandardScaler(),
             make_column_selector(dtype_include=np.number))
    ])),
    ('model', LinearRegression())
])

sr_tree = DecisionTreeRegressor()

ct_imputation = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ('categorical',
        SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value='None'),
        make_column_selector(dtype_include='category')),
    ('numerical',
        SimpleImputer(strategy='median'),
        make_column_selector(dtype_include=np.number))
])

stacked_regressor = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputation', ct_imputation),
    ('back_to_pandas', FunctionTransformer(
        func=lambda values: pd.DataFrame(values, columns=ct_imputation.get_feature_names_out())
    )),
    ('model', StackingRegressor(
        regressors=[sr_linear, sr_tree],
        meta_regressor=DecisionTreeRegressor(),
        use_features_in_secondary=True
    ))
])
```

Note that the "outer" `ColumnTransformer` (in `stacked_regressor`) returns a `numpy` matrix.
But the "inner" `ColumnTransformer` (in `sr_linear`) expects a `pandas.DataFrame`, so I had to convert the matrix back to a data frame using step `back_to_pandas`.
(To use `get_feature_names_out` I had to use the nightly version of sklearn, because the current stable 1.0.2 version does not support it yet. Fortunately it can be installed with [one simple command](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/advanced_installation.html).)

The above code fails when calling `stacked_regressor.fit()`, with the following error (the entire stacktrace is again in [the gist](https://gist.github.com/alberto-santini/d2c7572b499dea124a0160406fcf2e40)):

```
ValueError: make_column_selector can only be applied to pandas dataframes
```

However, because I added the `back_to_pandas` step to my outer pipeline, the inner pipelines *should* be getting a pandas data frame!
In fact, if I only `fit_transform()` my `ct_imputation` object, I clearly obtain a pandas data frame.
I cannot understand where and when exactly the data which gets passed around ceases to be a data frame.
Why is my code failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct thing to do was:

1. Move from `mlxtend`'s to `sklearn`'s `StackingRegressor`. I believe the former was creater when `sklearn` still didn't have a stacking regressor. Now there is no need to use more 'obscure' solutions. `sklearn`'s stacking regressor works pretty well.
2. Move the 1-hot-encoding step to the outer pipeline, because (surprisingly!) `sklearn`'s `DecisionTreeRegressor` cannot handle categorical data among the features.

A working version of the code is given below:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, make_pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer, make_column_selector
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import StackingRegressor

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def set_correct_categories(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    for column in df.columns:
        if df[column].dtype == object or 'MSSubClass' in column:
            df[column] = pd.Categorical(df[column])

    return df

d = fetch_openml('house_prices', as_frame=True).frame
d = set_correct_categories(d).drop(columns='Id')

sr_linear = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('preprocessing', StandardScaler()),
    ('model', LinearRegression())
])

ct_preprocessing = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ('categorical',
        make_pipeline(
            SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value='None'),
            OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, handle_unknown='ignore')
        ),
        make_column_selector(dtype_include='category')),
    ('numerical',
        SimpleImputer(strategy='median'),
        make_column_selector(dtype_include=np.number))
])

stacking_regressor = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('preprocessing', ct_preprocessing),
    ('model', StackingRegressor(
        estimators=[('linear_regression', sr_linear), ('regression_tree', DecisionTreeRegressor())],
        final_estimator=DecisionTreeRegressor(),
        passthrough=True
    ))
])

label = 'SalePrice'
features = [col for col in d.columns if col != label]
X, y = d[features], d[label]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, shuffle=True)

stacking_regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Thanks to user amiola for [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71180009/436007) putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Imo the issue has to be ascribed to `StackingRegressor`. Actually, I am not an expert on its usage and still I have not explored its source code, but I've found this [sklearn issue - #16473](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/16473) which seems implying that *<< the concatenation [of regressors and meta_regressors] does not preserve dataframe >>* (though this is referred to `sklearn` `StackingRegressor` instance, rather than on `mlxtend` one).

Indeed, have a look at what happens once you replace it with your `sr_linear` pipeline:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, make_pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer, make_column_selector
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder, FunctionTransformer
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from mlxtend.regressor import StackingRegressor

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# We use the Ames house prices dataset for this example
d = fetch_openml('house_prices', as_frame=True).frame

# Small data preprocessing:
for column in d.columns:
    if d[column].dtype == object or column == 'MSSubClass':
        d[column] = pd.Categorical(d[column])
    
d.drop(columns='Id', inplace=True)

# Prepare the data for training
label = 'SalePrice'
features = [col for col in d.columns if col != label]
X, y = d[features], d[label]

# Train the stacked regressor
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, shuffle=True)

sr_linear = Pipeline(steps=[
('preprocessing', ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ('categorical',
         make_pipeline(OneHotEncoder(), StandardScaler(with_mean=False)),
         make_column_selector(dtype_include='category')),
     ('numerical',
         StandardScaler(),
         make_column_selector(dtype_include=np.number))
    ])),
    ('model', LinearRegression())
])

ct_imputation = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ('categorical',
        SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='constant', fill_value='None'),
        make_column_selector(dtype_include='category')),
    ('numerical',
        SimpleImputer(strategy='median'),
        make_column_selector(dtype_include=np.number))
])

stacked_regressor = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputation', ct_imputation),
    ('back_to_pandas', FunctionTransformer(
        func=lambda values: pd.DataFrame(values, columns=ct_imputation.get_feature_names_out()).astype(types)
    )),
    ('mdl', sr_linear)
])

stacked_regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Observe that I had to slightly modify the `'back_to_pandas'` step because for some reason `pd.DataFrame` was changing the `dtypes` of the columns to `'object'` only (from `'category'` and `'float64'`),  therefore clashing with the imputation performed in `sr_linear`. For this reason, I've applied `.astype(types)` to the `pd.DataFrame` constructor, where `types` is defined as follows (based on the implementation of `.get_feature_names_out()` method of the `SimpleImputer` from the *dev* version of `sklearn`):

```
types = {} 
for col in d.columns[:-1]: 
    if d[col].dtype == 'category':
        types['categorical__' + col] = str(d[col].dtype)
    else:
        types['numerical__' + col] = str(d[col].dtype)
```

Comment: Good catch about the column types. I had already investigated `mlxtend` source and I had not found anything suspicious. I see that removing the stacked regressor makes things work. I also replaced mlxtend's object with sklearn's one and, as you say, I "lose" the dataframe and this confuses the models: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'RL'`. The only solution is possibly to write my own StackingRegressor object.

Comment: Ah, wait! That error is just because sklearn's `DecisionTreeRegressor` does not support categorical features. After one-hot-encoding it actually works. I will post an answer with the solution.